# Python 3.5 Beautiful soup 4 Error UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.5

I try to use BeautifulSoup 4. After I successfully installed, there is always some error and I can't fix it for "soup= BeautifulSoup(html)"

When I use following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

it shows the error:

```
//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py:166: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

To get rid of this warning, change this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup])

to this:

  BeautifulSoup([your markup], "lxml")

  markup_type=markup_type))
Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "<ipython-input-13-d4b16f497b1d>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('/Users/beckswu/Desktop/coursera/using python access web data/class 2.py', wdir='/Users/beckswu/Desktop/coursera/using python access web data')

   File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

   File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 88, in execfile
exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

   File "/Users/beckswu/Desktop/coursera/using python access web data/class 2.py", line 37, in <module>
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

   File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 212, in __init__
markup, from_encoding, exclude_encodings=exclude_encodings)):

   File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/builder/_lxml.py", line 108, in prepare_markup
markup, try_encodings, is_html, exclude_encodings)

TypeError: __init__() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Then I change my code to

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
markup_type=markup_type))
```

It also shows the Error

```
    markup_type=markup_type))
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I fix that? I appreciate anyone's help.

Comment: What d you think `markup_type=markup_type` is doing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an error in your code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
# if you decide to use html as parser 
soup = BeautifulSoup("html", features="html.parser") 

## the third parameter is the **builder** and it defaults to None, so you dont have to add it. Actually it is not **markup_type**
```

If you dont have lxml, you can install it by running:

```
pip install lxml
```

Then you import it and use like this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
soup = BeautifulSoup("html", "lxml")
```

The parameters of BeautifulSoup constructor are:

markup="", features=None, builder=None, parse_only=None, from_encoding=None, exclude_encodings=None and **kwargs.

Answer (score -1):

instead of the html,you need the pass the text file of the html as below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
request = requests.get("http://www.flipkart.com/search").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(request)
```

Hope this helps :)